# Bal persist returns the error `related entity does not have the corresponding relation field`

Tags: persistence, ballerina

Consider the following Ballerina code,

```
import ballerina/persist as _;

type Phone record {|
    readonly string id;
    string number;
    boolean textOK;
    boolean whatsappOK;
    boolean callOK;
    Person person;
|};

type Person record {|
    readonly string id;
    string name;
    string[] email;
    Phone[] phones;
    House house;
|};

type House record {|
    readonly string id;
    int number;
    Person[] owners;
    boolean isRented;
    Person[] residents;
|};
```

Following error is generated when the `bal persist generate` command is used for the second relationship to a person from house. Is there something wrong with the above code?

```
% bal persist generate              
ERROR: failed to generate types and client for the definition file(model.bal). the model definition file(model.bal) has errors.
ERROR [model.bal:(25:5,25:24)] the related entity Person does not have the corresponding relation field
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is related to having two one-many relationships between Person and House entities.  In this case, there should be a corresponding relation field for both of these relations in the entity Person. You can fix the above issue by changing the Person entity into the following form

```
type Person record {|
    readonly string id;
    string name;
    string[] email;
    Phone[] phones;
    House ownedHouse;
    House residence;
|};
```

In addition to the above approach, you can also use many-many associations for the above case. In this case, the model file would take the following form.

```
import ballerina/persist as _;


type Phone record {|
   readonly string id;
   string number;
   boolean textOK;
   boolean whatsappOK;
   boolean callOK;
   Person person;
|};


type Person record {|
   readonly string id;
   string name;
   string[] email;
   Phone[] phones;
   HouseAssociation[] houses;
|};


type HouseAssociation record {|
   readonly string id;
   string name;
   House house;
   Person person;
   boolean isOwner;
|};


type House record {|
   readonly string id;
   int number;
   boolean isRented;
   HouseAssociation[] person;
|};
```